# Comparison between socket.io and UDP diagram for realtime streaming

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, udp, socket.io

I am using node.js as server and android as a client, I want to exchange bitmaps in real time as a streaming between server and android devices and even with using the broadcast sometimes.

Is it advisable to use **socket.io** for video streaming, videoconferencing, and all exchanges that probably should be of **UDP** ?

I know that:

> Socket.IO aims to make realtime apps possible in every browser and
>   mobile device.

But, what is the best way for me ? to use **socket.io** or **UDP** datagrams ? and why ?